# 'var' in javascript is not storing the value

Tags: javascript, dom, var

i am learning javascript and ,i don't understand why var won't hold this value.

```
function animate(oning){
  var hello=document.querySelector("."+oning).classList.add("pressed");
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    hello.classList.remove("pressed");
  },100)

}
```

console logging this comes down as:

*Uncaught TypError:cannot read property classList of undefined*.

Why isn't var storing the value?

Comment: `hello` stores exactly the value you assign to it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add

Comment: The `.add()` method always returns `undefined`.

Comment: @CalebMiller he chained it with `.classList.add()` thats why it returned undefined. `.querySelector()` returns `null` if nothing was found =)

Comment: You need to set hello=document.querySelector("."+oning) hello will then be the first element with that selector. Then you can add the class to it.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest staying with fundamentals of object-oriented programming for a little while before moving to JavaScript in the browser. The APIs which web browsers expose are based on object-oriented programming and, without its understanding, it’ll all still be a dark magic. But let’s look at your specific problem…

There’s a lot of work going on those lines. Let’s unpack the second line:

```js
var hello=document.querySelector("."+oning).classList.add("pressed”);
```

You can rewrite it like this:

```js
var sel = "." + oning;
var el = document.querySelector(sel); // document.querySelector("."+oning)
var clsList = el.classList;           // document.querySelector("."+oning)
                                      //   .classList

clsList.add("pressed");               // document.querySelector("."+oning)
                                      //   .classList.add("pressed”)

var hello;
```

I’ve separated individual expressions from right-hand side of the assignment. It shows the order of execution and how one expression depends on another.

Then, you can see that `clsList.add("pressed")` is alone there and has no impact on your variable `hello`. This is because the `add()` method is changing element’s class list (mutating, or modifying in-place might be some of the programmer’s lingo). In this particular case and given some conventions, the `add()` method has nothing useful to return back about the action it has done. In other words, the `add()` method has no return value.
Some mutating methods might return a value. For example, `true` or `false` to indicate whether they succeeded or not, or a number like `push()` on array indicating a number of elements in that array. You can guess sometimes or eventually memorize, but it’s always best to consult documentation – for example, Teemu referenced [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org) in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720912/var-in-javascript-is-not-storing-the-value#comment116199111_65720912) which is a great source with examples, references to formal specifications, and availability of particular API in different web browsers.

As you’ve experienced yourself, you can surely write:

```js
var hello = clsList.add("pressed");
```

It’s still valid code and it executes just fine. However, it doesn’t do what you probably want. A method call which doesn’t return anything in general programming sense, actually returns a special value `undefined` in JavaScript. That’s JavaScript’s way of saying: “I’m not returning anything. I’m doing what you told me and you don’t have to care about the result. If you care, check elsewhere…” There’s no point in storing a result of a method call which doesn’t return anything.

Well, that’s all good and well… “But how to fix it?” you might ask.

Let’s start with an intent. We want a function called `animate()` to add the CSS class `pressed` on an element whose class name will be passed as a parameter. After a brief moment (100ms), we will remove the class. I guess this might trigger some CSS animation (not the best way if you ask me, but who am I to judge…). Let’s explore one way the code can “crystallize”:

1. Define a function:

   ```js
   function animate() {

   }
   ```
2. Receive a class name of an element to animate:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {

   }
   ```
3. Find the element:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {
     document.querySelector("." + oning);
   }
   ```
4. Add a CSS class to our element:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {
     document.querySelector("." + oning).classList.add("pressed");
   }
   ```
5. Do something later:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {
     document.querySelector("." + oning).classList.add("pressed");

     setTimeout(function() {

     }, 100);
   }
   ```
6. That something is removing the CSS class from our element:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {
     document.querySelector("." + oning).classList.add("pressed");

     setTimeout(function() {
       document.querySelector("." + oning).classList.remove("pressed");
     }, 100);
   }
   ```
7. If you still want to use a variable, perhaps to improve readability:

   ```js
   function animate(oning) {
     var hello = document.querySelector("." + oning).classList;

     hello.add("pressed");

     setTimeout(function() {
       hello.remove("pressed");
     }, 100);
   }
   ```

Notice, that I store `classList` reference for later. That is our object of interest. Then, I call `add()` on that class list. And later, I call `remove()` on that same class list we stored earlier. A class list object can manipulate all of element’s classes and provide additional useful methods to work with list of CSS class name. In fact, it’s an instance of [`DOMTokenList` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) which is used in other places when you work with Web APIs (or DOM specifically), not just to add or remove CSS class names.

If you find names like object, instance, interface, method, method call, parameter, or reference ambiguous believe that they have quite specific meaning. They and many others define what’s called object-oriented programming which is one computer programming paradigm. Is I said in the begging, Web API exposed by web browsers are defined within this paradigm. You should learn the fundamentals of that paradigm first. Although possible, I actually think, it’s not a good idea to learn OOP and Web APIs at the same time. The Web is very complex and often inconsistent for reasons which don’t make sense without knowing its history. But that would be another topic.